# Retrain of a neural network

Tags: mathematical-modeling, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have already trained a NN with training data set $[X,Y]$. Lets consider this model is called $M$. Now, I have a new data set $[X_{new}, Y_{new}]$. I would like to Update my model $M$ with data set $[X_{new}, Y_{new}]$ without retraining it from scratch.

My question is: is it possible to update the model this way or I must retrain this? If it is possible to update, how?

Comment: Probably better posted elsewhere - perhaps theoretical computer science

Comment: @EthanBolker Not theoretical computer science, that's for sure. Maybe cross validated or stackoverflow.

Comment: My understanding of NNs is only rudimentary, but I would be wary of training using only the new set. It may forget all it's learned from the old set, as if it's training from scratch with a random setting that just happens to be good at some set which is not the one it's training on. Maybe continue training it from where you left off, but feed it a mix of new and old data?

Comment: You may take a look at the recent papers by Gorban and Tyukin. Search for   "Correction of Legacy AI Systems". The approach they develop isn't  very simple though